# How can I select the latest entry of mySQL database table?

Tags: php, mysql

I select the latest inserted `id` from my mySQL database. I also want to select the appropriate `name` to that latest `id`.

```
$pdo = $db->query('SELECT *,MAX(id) AS latest FROM data');
    while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         $id = $row["latest"];
         $name = $row["name"];
    }
```

The selecting of the `id` is working well. But not the latest `name` is selected, instead always the `name` of the first row of my table is selected. It doesn't fit to the `id`

Comment: you can simply use `order by id` DESC and take the 1st result

Comment: Mostly a duplicate of the above, except you need to order by primary key instead of timestamp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just

```
SELECT name, id FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: OK, good idea! I will check it out

Comment: or even `SELECT *` and then you can foreach anything within `data`

Comment: the user mishanon suggested another method `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, is there any advantage or difference in those methods?

Comment: f you use LAST_INSERT_ID you will be getting the last row inserted by this session. Which may or may not be the highest valued id in the table

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will only work if you have just inserted a new row and are still in the same MYSQL session

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write following answer but i have to confess that i find e4c5's answer better.

```
SELECT * FROM data where id = (SELECT max(id) FROM data)
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much